# libgit2 - clone operation with Github

Tags: git, github, libgit2

I am having a heck of a time getting libgit2 to clone. This example of using clone is taken almost verbatim from their documentation.

It seems libgit2 is crashing while trying to delete 'core.symlinks' key in the git repo it just created as part of clone.

Does anyone know how to correctly clone a github repo using libgit2.

libgit2 - stable - **v0.21.1**

```
#include <git2.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct { 
int a;
/* … */ } progress_data;

int fetch_progress(
            const git_transfer_progress *stats,
            void *payload)
{
  progress_data *pd = (progress_data*)payload;

    int fetch_percent =
        (100 * stats->received_objects) /
        stats->total_objects;
    int index_percent =
        (100 * stats->indexed_objects) /
        stats->total_objects;
    int kbytes = stats->received_bytes / 1024;

    printf("network %3d%% (%4d kb, %5d/%5d)  /"
            "  index %3d%% (%5d/%5d)\n",
            fetch_percent, kbytes,
            stats->received_objects, stats->total_objects,
            index_percent,
            stats->indexed_objects, stats->total_objects);

//  printf("in fetch_progress\n");


  /* Do something with network transfer progress */
}



void checkout_progress(
            const char *path,
            size_t cur,
            size_t tot,
            void *payload)
{
  progress_data *pd = (progress_data*)payload;

  printf("in checkout_progress\n");

  /* Do something with checkout progress */
}


int main(void) {

    /* … */
    progress_data d = { 0 };
    git_clone_options clone_opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    git_checkout_options checkout_opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;

    checkout_opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE;
    checkout_opts.progress_cb = checkout_progress;
    checkout_opts.progress_payload = &d;


    clone_opts.checkout_opts = checkout_opts;
    clone_opts.remote_callbacks.transfer_progress = fetch_progress;
//  clone_opts.remote_callbacks.fetch_progress_cb = fetch_progress;
    clone_opts.remote_callbacks.payload = &d;

    git_repository *repo = NULL;

    const char *url = "git://github.com/WigWagCo/twlib";
    const char *path = "tmp";

    int error = git_clone(&repo, url, path, &clone_opts);

    sleep(15);

}
```

and the crash:

```
$ gdb --args ./a.out 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
...
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ed/work/devicejs/tools/packageTools/a.out 
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
a.out: ../vendor/libgit2/src/global.c:274: git__global_state: Assertion `git_atomic_get(&git__n_inits) > 0' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6c8c425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6c8c425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff6c8fb8b in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
#2  0x00007ffff6c850ee in __assert_fail_base (fmt=<optimized out>, assertion=0x4bad88 "git_atomic_get(&git__n_inits) > 0", file=0x4bad50 "../vendor/libgit2/src/global.c", line=<optimized out>, function=<optimized out>)
    at assert.c:94
#3  0x00007ffff6c85192 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x4bad88 "git_atomic_get(&git__n_inits) > 0", file=0x4bad50 "../vendor/libgit2/src/global.c", line=274, function=0x4badb0 "git__global_state") at assert.c:103
#4  0x0000000000411cd3 in git__global_state () at ../vendor/libgit2/src/global.c:274
#5  0x000000000040e06a in set_error (error_class=7, string=0x6f8670 "Could not find key 'core.symlinks' to delete") at ../vendor/libgit2/src/errors.c:23
#6  0x000000000040e247 in giterr_set (error_class=7, string=0x4ba350 "Could not find key '%s' to delete") at ../vendor/libgit2/src/errors.c:74
#7  0x000000000040b9da in config_delete (cfg=0x6f8230, name=0x4bc555 "core.symlinks") at ../vendor/libgit2/src/config_file.c:611
#8  0x00000000004082d4 in git_config_delete_entry (cfg=0x6f80a0, name=0x4bc555 "core.symlinks") at ../vendor/libgit2/src/config.c:606
#9  0x000000000041ebc6 in repo_init_fs_configs (cfg=0x6f80a0, cfg_path=0x6f8190 "/home/ed/work/devicejs/tools/packageTools/tmp/.git/config", repo_dir=0x6f8130 "/home/ed/work/devicejs/tools/packageTools/tmp/.git/", 
    work_dir=0x6f80e0 "/home/ed/work/devicejs/tools/packageTools/tmp/", update_ignorecase=true) at ../vendor/libgit2/src/repository.c:968
#10 0x000000000041ed4d in repo_init_config (repo_dir=0x6f8130 "/home/ed/work/devicejs/tools/packageTools/tmp/.git/", work_dir=0x6f80e0 "/home/ed/work/devicejs/tools/packageTools/tmp/", flags=196624, mode=0)
    at ../vendor/libgit2/src/repository.c:1015
#11 0x000000000041fc4b in git_repository_init_ext (out=0x7fffffffded0, given_repo=0x4b9bf8 "tmp", opts=0x7fffffffde50) at ../vendor/libgit2/src/repository.c:1483
#12 0x000000000041fac2 in git_repository_init (repo_out=0x7fffffffded0, path=0x4b9bf8 "tmp", is_bare=0) at ../vendor/libgit2/src/repository.c:1446
#13 0x00000000004068da in git_clone (out=0x7fffffffdff8, url=0x4b9bd8 "git://github.com/WigWagCo/twlib", local_path=0x4b9bf8 "tmp", _options=0x7fffffffe090) at ../vendor/libgit2/src/clone.c:403
#14 0x0000000000405a53 in main ()
(gdb) q
```

Answer (score 1):

The folks github's libgit2 responded:

Here is a working clone of a repo with libgit2 v0.21.1 (threads enabled):

```
#include <git2.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int COMPLETE = 0;


typedef struct { 
int a;
/* … */ } progress_data;

int fetch_progress(
            const git_transfer_progress *stats,
            void *payload)
{
  progress_data *pd = (progress_data*)payload;

    int fetch_percent =
        (100 * stats->received_objects) /
        stats->total_objects;
    int index_percent =
        (100 * stats->indexed_objects) /
        stats->total_objects;
    int kbytes = stats->received_bytes / 1024;

    printf("network %3d%% (%4d kb, %5d/%5d)  /"
            "  index %3d%% (%5d/%5d)\n",
            fetch_percent, kbytes,
            stats->received_objects, stats->total_objects,
            index_percent,
            stats->indexed_objects, stats->total_objects);

    if(stats->indexed_objects >= stats->total_objects) {
        printf("COMPLETE=1\n");
        COMPLETE = 1;
    }

  /* Do something with network transfer progress */
    return 0; // return 0 for success. ~src/common.h:95 for info
}



void checkout_progress(
            const char *path,
            size_t cur,
            size_t tot,
            void *payload)
{
  progress_data *pd = (progress_data*)payload;

  printf("in checkout_progress\n");


  /* Do something with checkout progress */
}


int complete_cb(git_remote_completion_type type, void *data) {

    printf("complete\n");
}




int main(void) {

    git_threads_init();
    /* … */
    progress_data d = { 0 };
    git_clone_options clone_opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    git_checkout_options checkout_opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;

    checkout_opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE;
    checkout_opts.progress_cb = checkout_progress;
    checkout_opts.progress_payload = &d;


    clone_opts.checkout_opts = checkout_opts;
    clone_opts.remote_callbacks.transfer_progress = fetch_progress;
    clone_opts.remote_callbacks.payload = &d;

    clone_opts.remote_callbacks.completion = complete_cb;

    git_repository *repo = NULL;

    const char *url = "git://github.com/WigWagCo/twlib";
    const char *path = "./tmp";


    printf("wait for completion.\n");


    int error = git_clone(&repo, url, path, &clone_opts);

    if(!COMPLETE)
        printf("Clone failed.\n");
    else
        printf("Clone complete.\n");

    printf("\n");
    if (error != 0) {
        const git_error *err = giterr_last();
        if (err) printf("ERROR %d: %s\n", err->klass, err->message);
        else printf("ERROR %d: no detailed info\n", error);
    } else
        if(repo) git_repository_free(repo);

    git_threads_shutdown();

}

/**
Build:
g++ -I./vendor/libgit2/include testhttps.cc ./build/Release/git2.a ./build/Release/zlib.a ./build/Release/http_parser.a -lpthread -lssl -lssh2 -lrt

 */
```

Comment: You should update your answer because it does not longer works.

Comment: You should probably call `git_libgit2_init` https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/libgit2/git_libgit2_init

Comment: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/9894c7ddeb204d0568e1173f0f9bb48580ece010 is also of interest.